# Finding Numbers where modulo is k

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have given a Number A  where `1<=A<=10^6` and a Number K. I have to find the all the numbers between 1 to A where  `A%i==k` and i is `1<=i<=A`. Is there any better solution than looping
**Simple Solution**

```
for(int i=1;i<=A;i++)
   if(A%i==k) count++;
```

Is there any better solution than iterating all the numbers between 1 to A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `A % i == k` is equivalent to `A == n * i + k` for any integer value of `n` that gives a value of `A` within the stated bounds.

This can be rearranged as `n * i = A - k`, and can be solved by finding all the factors of `A - k` that are multiples of `i` (where `k < i <= A`).

Here are a couple of examples:

```
A = 100, k = 10
F = factor_list(A-k) = factor_list(90) = [1,2,3,5,6,9,10,15,18,30,45,90]
(discard all factors less than or equal to k)
Result: [15,18,30,45,90]

A = 288, k = 32
F = [2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]
Result: [64,128,256]
```

If `A - k` is prime, then there is either one solution (`A-k`) or none (if `A-k <= k`).